# Insertar elemento HTML dentro del primer hijo de otro elemento. JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, script

Quiero en el siguiente codigo, mover el elemento .buscarusuarios dentro del primer TD hijo del TR classe fltrow, una vez que se inicie el dom. Ando un poco perdido con los selectores de CSS3

```
<form class="buscarusuarios">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"  
type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">     
</form>

<tr class="fltrow">
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>       
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto necesitas clonar el formulario con`.cloneNode`, agregar el clon al elemento que deseas con `appendChild ()` y al final eliminar el formulario inicial utilizando `parentNode.removeChild`. No es jQuery, es javascript. Espero que sea útil.

```js
let primer_hijo_de_fltrow = document.querySelector("table .fltrow td")

let formulario = document.querySelector(".buscarusuarios");

let nuevo_formulario = formulario.cloneNode(true);
primer_hijo_de_fltrow.appendChild(nuevo_formulario);

formulario.parentNode.removeChild(formulario);
```

```css
td{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<form class="buscarusuarios">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"  
type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">     
</form>


<table>
<tr class="fltrow">
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>
<td>Prueba</td>       
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Super excelente, muchas gracias, me sirvió perfecto.